# Hamburger icon not opening navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

When i open my app and click on the hamburger icon, it is does not open the navigation drawer. But when i swipe from the edges it is opening. Also the drawer responds to hamburger icon click events after the swipe action.

I tried every solution on stackoverflow but couldn't resolve the issue. Please someone help. Thanks in advance.

XML Code:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:title="Nexzen"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/dark_green"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/dark_green"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicator="@color/receive_message"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/receive_message"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navmenu"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/text_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/text_color"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    android:layout_gravity = "start" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Activity code :

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    
            setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
    
            toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, binding.drawer, binding.toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
            toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getColor(R.color.white));
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            toggle.setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(true);
            binding.drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
    
        }
    
    @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                binding.drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            toggle.syncState();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you haven't set the visibility of the NavigationView in the fragment to invisible or gone. This was the cause for me.

Swiping must make the navigation drawer visible. Clicking the hamburger button does not.